# Using a stored procedure, adding a column with data not from a table

Tags: sql

Ive not really done much SQL in like 9 years so apologies if i seem a bit clueless.

So I have a stored procedure. It gets information from 5 different tables. I want to add another column but the information going into this column will not be coming from another table. Adding the column to the return set is fine.

I want to add the filepath to a picture as the data in that column. This isnt stored in any table. So can someone tell me the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please post at least a snippet of the code you have now.

Comment: And as it is a procedure what RDBMS are you working on ?

Comment: Why the down votes for this guy?

Comment: @MichaelRice Just guessing here but the poster didn't do even basic research before posting this question. The answer to this is part of the documentation of most DB servers.

Comment: @MichaelRice (Not a down voter) I guess because people could not contemplate that the answer to this question might have been that simple :)

Comment: Unclear what is being asked.  Are you trying to add a *constant* as a column?  Prefix an existing column with a constant?  Resolve the full path of a filename?  Please show your current code and what you expect the resulting dataset to contain.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly you can just add a static column.

```
SELECT Col1, 
    Col2, 
    'http://MyFilePath' AS FilePath
FROM
    Mytables
JOIN...
```

Comment: He is asking how to pull data from another table, but you have suggested that he just return a constant.  I suspect the confusion is because he wants to use the same path prefix for everything, but he still needs to pull data from another table to append to the path prefix.

Comment: The question asker said it would NOT be coming from a table:
" want to add another column but the information going into this column will NOT be coming from another table." -- See my caps.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I totally misread that.  I tried to reverse my vote, but it won't let me since it was 6 mins ago.  If you edit your question, it will let me reverse my vote.

Comment: My poor formatting. Nooo...! :-)